# AjaxControlToolkit - Can't get AutoCompleteExtender working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I can't get the AutoCompleteExtender working. It's probably something trivial. Using .NET 4 default ASP.NET project in VS2010.

Code:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="example" autocomplete="off" />
<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender
            ID="autocomplete"
            runat="server" 
            TargetControlID="example"
            ServicePath="~/services/AutoComplete.asmx" 
            ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" 
            CompletionInterval="1" />
```

The web service works - the code is copied practically verbatim from the AJAX Control Toolkit samples. This is really frustrating me. I have looked at other questions on here and not found a solution yet.

I don't get any errors or exceptions. Typing in the text box doesn't do anything, the web service doesn't hit the break point.

Comment: do you get any errors? what is the behavior?

Comment: I don't get any errors or exceptions. Typing in the text box doesn't do anything, the web service doesn't hit the break point.

Comment: Put a break point in the service and see if it triggers.  Make sure that you don't have any permission issues.  Also make sure that your service is decorated with the [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService] attribute to communicate via JSON.

Comment: The answer suggested by Brian worked when I made it a page method, however, I would rather use the web service to avoid code duplication. Ideas? There must be an error logged somewhere, even if it's a Not Found - how do I find it.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this example, make sure yours match: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_AutoComplete_simple.ashx

Also, make sure the web service has the exact parameters; if not the same signature, that can be problematic too.

HTH.

Comment: This worked. Now my issue is with the web service refusing to fire.

Comment: Did you add a pointer to the web service to the ScriptManager control too?

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that you have the casing of the names of the input parameter correct:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
public string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count)
```

Make sure that you use **prefixText** and **count** with correct casing.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not it unfortunately. The web service is copied verbatim from the sample code.

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to me more than once on new websites where I reuse my AutoCompleteExtender-based UserControls.  I recommend you use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to capture and inspect the POST from your browser and the response from your server.  It's a breeze to install and launch.  Once it's running, you type a few characters into your TextBox, then check the Web Session entries that Fiddler captures.  If you see one or more entries with error codes, inspect them for the error details that were generated by your IIS (or ASP.Net) server.  You'll usually get to the bottom of it very quickly that way.

Most recently, my issue was that I forgot to uncomment the ScriptService attribute of the WebService class:

```
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the ~/ from the Service path.

```
 ServicePath="services/AutoComplete.asmx"
```